# how to pipe powershell commands in dotnet core

Tags: c#, linux, powershell, .net-core

I have a strange issue in a linux docker image.

The code below works perfectly on Windows computer and in Visual studio but doesn't work in a linux pod in kubernetes.

Essentially I'm trying to get the list of users with mailboxes from Office 365.

Graph Api is not an option as it does not make the difference between users, archives, shared mailboxes, etc...

This syntax throws an exception of type basic authentication failure.
If I remove the pipe, it works. It means that the credentials are not passed through the pipe.
Very weird !

```
PSCommand commandMailBox = new PSCommand();
string request = "Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -archive | get-user | select firstname,lastname, windowsemailaddress";
commandMailBox.AddScript(request);
```

I replaced the code by this syntax:

```
        // Get MailBox User 
        PSCommand commandMailBox = new PSCommand();
        Pipeline pipeLine = _runspace.CreatePipeline();
        Command getMailBox = new Command("Get-Mailbox");
        getMailBox.Parameters.Add("ResultSize", "unlimited");
        getMailBox.Parameters.Add("RecipientTypeDetails", "UserMailbox");
        pipeLine.Commands.Add(getMailBox);
        Command getUser = new Command("get-user");
        pipeLine.Commands.Add(getUser);
        Command select = new Command("select-Object");
        var props = new string[] { "firstname", "lastname", "windowsemailaddress" };
        select.Parameters.Add("Property", props);
        pipeLine.Commands.Add(select);
        var mailBoxList = pipeLine.Invoke();
```

Again it works perfectly in Visual studio but returns no result in Linux.

Do you knwo how to solve this?

Comment: Powershell itself uses Graph and the other Office 365 APIs. There's simply no other way to talk to a remote HTTP service. Most likely you're using the wrong services or looking at the wrong docs. Or perhaps you've already found the relevant API but aren't using the correct parameters to filter results to just the types you want

Comment: As for the pipeline not working - is PowerShell Core installed? Are the credentials configured? Your code doesn't authenticate to Office 365 which means the authentication step was executed earlier and quite likely the API keys for the user are stored in the Windows account profile. You'd have to perform the equivalent steps on Linux

Comment: Remember to check `pipeline.HadErrors` and `pipeline.Errors` after `Invoke()` returns (my guess is you encounter the same authentication error as before)